# Umbraco installer wizard not showing up

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, umbraco, umbraco8

First time trying to install Umbraco. I followed the instructions on how to install Umbraco 8 with NuGet. (https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Install/install-umbraco-with-nuget)

But I'm having issues with getting the Umbraco installer to show up. After starting without debugging (Ctrl+F5) I just get the Chrome error page for ERRCONNECTIONRESET. It does seem some resources are missing in my project solution. Tried cleaning and building the solution over and over, but no luck.

[image]

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 16.9.3 with .NET Framework 4.7.2 (also tried it with 4.8)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that Visual Studio navigated to the HTTPS variant. When I navigated to the HTTP variant, it works.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at [Paul Seal's video about how to install Umbraco v8](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PmAYWmH9BhE&list=PL90L_HquhD-_N2mO8kYzhZL15sh1lyxVK&index=2), hopefully, this will help you do your installation successfully.

PS: From the error message you have shared, I can't be sure what is missing but if you follow Paul Seal's steps, which are the default Umbraco installation steps, you should be able to create an Umbraco website.

Comment: Thank you, I followed his instructions but I still faced the issue. After navigating to the HTTP website, it started working.

Comment: Thanks for the update Stephan, glad it is working now.